# Maven doesn't recognize jaxws-ri version

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, dependencies, dependency-management, jaxws-maven-plugin

I'm very new to Web development, but I can't figure out what's happening here:

[pom.xml file not recognizing version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XO6ny.png)

I'm working on a project with multiple repositories, that depend on each other. All my repositories can be seen on the left of the image there, and the dependencies go: utils > dao > base_services > api_rest > integradores > geracao_de_boletos > ws > webjar >web (where web depends on all that came before it to work).

All was cool until, for some god forsaken reason, a dependency I used called 'Jrimum' simply stopped working. It was no big deal, since they have a rival that does the exact same thing, so I just took a day to migrate from one to the other and thought that was that.

Except out of nowhere, when I try to perform Maven's clean/ install protocol, now ANOTHER dependency has an error, that, as far as I know, didn't have the error before!

That's the dependency you see on screen there: "jaxws-ri". When I run mvn clean install, the following error appears:

> "Failure to find com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-ri:pom:2.3.3-b01 in https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of org.jboss.repository.releases has elapsed or updates are forced"

Now, this bogles my mind, because, if I go to the original Maven dependency website (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.ws/jaxws-ri),[the version exists there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14eaQ.png) (Mind the edit at the end of the post!)
Now, I know the version that I'm trying to use seems a little dodgy, but I've tried other versions on my POM file and it doesn't recognize them either.

Maven version is 3.6.1 and IDE is Intellij Ultimate.

EDIT: So, apparently, the website I thought to be the original Maven sources, isn't! Instead, I've been directed to "https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.sun.xml.ws/docs/2.3.3-b01/pom" (thanks to  user khmarbaise by the way). And when I ctrl C + ctrl V the Maven dependency example,
[it fixes my initial problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olFYi.png), which is absolutely great! But it also creates [a bunch of other problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImXKc.png) on other libraries...

(Error message seen on screen is "bad path element "C:\Users\Dunning.m2\repository\com\mchange\c3p0\0.9.5.3\mchange-commons-java-0.2.15.jar": no such file or directory")

So, my new question is: do dependencies have other dependencies? Is the error being caused because this dependency that got added (properly now), has other dependencies of it's own?

Comment: The website you are mentioning `if I go to the orininal Maven dependenci website` is simply not Maven Central...This is the offical Central repository: https://search.maven.org/

Comment: Ahn I see! But this didn't quite fix everything...Im gonna update the post explaining. Thanks!

Comment: You have made a dependency with the type `pom` which does not make sense cause a pom does not contain code so it could not be part of the classpath...apart from that you should try to avoid com.sun etc.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, but I don't really understand... as I said, im still kinda new to the whole web development using Maven thing... So I was under the assumption that the depenency on the pom.xml file was the path used by Maven to download the resources of the library. What you're saying is that when i put "pom" on the tag  "<type>" im not importing the library, but instead another pom.xml file? And if so, how do I avoid doing that? Also, as I added on my main question, can depenencies have other depenencies of their own? Thanks so much for the help and atention.